# Auto-complet pure javascript removal

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build an auto-complete form with Javascript, PHP and Mysql.

Here's the constraints :

- No JQuery, pure Javascript
- No xmlHTTPResquest object, just DSL
- No innerHTML, just dom object moves.

The research works fine and are display correctly, but I can't delete them at each new search, they pile up and create a huge pile of divs.

I've tried a while statement with remove child and finally I've tried the function simpel() below, but no luck.

Anyone has an idea to complete that ?

Thanks,

Here's my javascript :

```
var planetx = document.querySelector('form:nth-of-type(1)');
var results = document.querySelector('article div:nth-of-type(1)');


function displayFile(data) {
        results.style.display = data.length ? "block" : "none";
        for (var i = 0, c = data.length; i < c; i++) {
                div = document.createElement('div');
                p = document.createElement('p');
                text = document.createTextNode(data[i]);
                p.appendChild(text);
                div.appendChild(p);
                text.className += "res";
                p.className += "res";
                div.className += "res";
                planetx.appendChild(div);
            }
}

function simpel() {
        h = document.querySelectorAll('.res');
        for (var k = 0, c = h.length; k < c; k++) {
            h[k].parentNode.removeChild;
        }
}




planetx.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
                                                var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
                                                scriptElement.type = 'text/Javascript';
                                                scriptElement.src = 'php/mysqlfile.php?name=' + e.target.value;
                                                document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
                        }, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why jQuery is not being used here, but that is besides the point. I see that this method is not actually being ran:

```
h[k].parentNode.removeChild
```

Not sure if this is the fix, but try adding "()" to call this method:

```
h[k].parentNode.removeChild(CHILD_TO_REMOVE)
```

EDIT:

```
h[k].remove();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I've tried that, no luck.

Comment: Try the new line that I added.

Comment: Sweet. Glad it works. If it answers the question, could you mark this answer as the right answer please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`removeChild` needs to be *called*, not just mentioned - and it needs a parameter (the node to delete):

```
h[k].parentNode.removeChild(h[k]);
```

Comment: What happens if your outer selector is changed to `h = document.querySelectorAll('div.res')`? In the current version, you're selecting the `div`, `p` and text nodes, all of which for some reason have the same class.

Comment: Thanks, tried that, no luck, results still piles up.